# Could I be the first to say that this is scam?

Tags: support, spam

https://superuser.com/q/979061/277991 is a scam. Could anyone vote this post as scam?

Comment: It's an ongoing spam pattern. I've flagged dozens of posts of this sort. See also: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9480/spambots-promoting-personal-enhancement-products-can-we-better-defend-against-t

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it refers to a specific question which has been deleted (and is not quoted), and therefore it is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meh. Flag it. Then other people flag it. Then it deeeeeead.

Unless a mod finds it. In which case its dead even faster.

Comment: A mod like you. With the ♦️.

Comment: Flagging means it turns up on our mod-flag list and gets it taken care of. If we mentioned all the spam we have here, meta would be overwhelmed.